# Document properties reset/deleted when new version released?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

We currently have a Google script add-on that uses the Properties Service (`getDocumentProperties()`, `setDocumentProperties()`) to store and retrieve document related value pairs.

However, it seems like every time a new version of the add-on is released this information is lost and/or reset !?

This is surprising since I would expect it to be persistent even through new releases. An option I am considering is using external dbs (JDBC) but I would rather avoid it if possible.

Do you know if there is a way to avoid this Document Properties reset for every new add-on release?

Comment: I assume you are talking about a published add-on working on a single specific document? How have you checked that the properties are actually getting reset?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to a published add-on working on a specific document but I did re-test today and actually they do preserve. Not sure what happened last time I checked but they disappeared - I was savings some colors so it was quite obvious when they were not saved. Anyway, it seems like they do persist which is great news and the logical thing to happen. I ll close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-checked and the document based properties of a script linked to a document persist after a new release which is great news. I'll leave it here in case anyone wonders about this very specific case.